# X,Y coordinates with reference points and find lat and long

Tags: coordinates

I have a floor map that is relayed on top of a grid and have the length and width of the floor along with 3 reference points that has x,y, lat, long.

Now I have some x,y that lies within the floor map and need to derive the lat and long for those points.

Is there a way to achieve that? Preferably Java but even a formula would do or some documentation.

Comment: Small (city level or less) scala? Just go to wikipedia and look about degree of latitude (and longitude): you have the formulas to get such lengths (on ellipsoids). Then it is just proportions. Note: such formulas are also very useful to see how much precision you should write down the lat/long numbers (for a given precision)

Comment: Small scale. We are talking in metres.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.